# Why do Object and var variables behave differently?

Tags: java, var, type-inference, java-10

Can someone explain the behavior of `o2`? Is it due to compiler optimization? Is it documented somewhere in the JLS?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o1 = new Object() {
            String getSomething() {
                return "AAA";
            }
        };
        // o1.getSomething(); // FAILS
        String methods1 = Arrays.toString(o1.getClass().getMethods());        
        var o2 = new Object() {
            String getSomething() {
                return "AAA";
            }
        };        
        o2.getSomething(); // OK        
        String methods2 = Arrays.toString(o2.getClass().getMethods());        
        System.out.println(methods1.equals(methods2));
    }    
}
```

The output produced is

> true

**[UPDATE]**

After some productive and useful discussion I think I can understand the behavior (please post comments if my assumption is wrong).

First off, thanks to **@user207421** who explained that the Java compiler treats the type of `o2` the same as the RHS, which:

- extends `Object`
- has the `getSomething` method

Then thanks to **@Joachim Sauer** who pointed to the proper place in the JLS.

Some more related JLS quotes:

> The type of the local variable is the upward projection of T with respect to all synthetic type variables mentioned by T (§4.10.5).
>
> Upward projection is applied to the type of the initializer when determining the type of the variable. If the type of the initializer contains capture variables, this projection maps the type of the initializer to a supertype that does not contain capture variables.
>
> While it would be possible to allow the type of the variable to mention capture variables, by projecting them away we enforce an attractive invariant that the scope of a capture variable is never larger than the statement containing the expression whose type is captured. Informally, capture variables cannot "leak" into subsequent statements.

Question: can we say that "capture variables" refers to `getSomething()` too in the context of the question?

And finally, thanks to **@Slaw** for pointing out that `getSomething` was declared package private so was not returned by `getMethods`.

Any comments/corrections appreciated.

Comment: It is because the type of `o1` is explicitly declared as `Object` while the type of `o2` is the same as the RHS, which *extends* `Object` and has the extra method, so you can call it.

Comment: @user207421 I like your explanation 'RHS' and this can be shown more detailed like this:

```new Object() {
            String getSomething() {
                return "AAA";
            }
        }.getSomething();
```
But I would love to see where is it clearly documented.

Comment: You have completely mangled what I said in your answer, so that it doesn't amount to what I said at all. Nor is your misinterpretation correct as to what the compiler actually does. What it does is assign the *type* of `o2` to be the same as the *type* of the RHS, that being exactly what `var` does. Which is documented in the JLS.

Comment: @user207421 sorry, indeed it made expression I credited you with something which you did not said, and when I made that demo code snippet I mean it conceptually, not literally. In any case, I updated the question again.

Comment: See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43987285/2711488).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object` has no method `getSomething`. And since `o1` is of type `Object` the compiler won't allow you to call `o1.getSomething`.

In the case of `o2` the type of the variable is the anonymous inner type that you created during initialization. That type has a `getSomething` method, so the compiler will allow you to call it.

Interestingly this is something that you can't directly do by having a named type. There's no type name that you use in the declaration of `o2` to get the same effect, because the type is anonymous.

It is defined in [JLS 14.4.1 Local Variable Declarators and Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4.1). Specifically this part:

> If LocalVariableType is var, then let T be the type of the initializer expression when treated as if it did not appear in an assignment context, and were thus a standalone expression (§15.2).

There's even an example that shows that below:

```
var d = new Object() {};  // d has the type of the anonymous class
```

Comment: I would love more technical answer, both *are* inner anonymous types. My question was why compiler does not complain for o2 (I know for sure why it complains for o1)

Comment: @BaratSahdzijeu: I don't quite understand: the type of `o1` is `Object` and `Object` doesn't have a `getSomething` method. That's about as technical as it gets ... The type of `o2` is **not** `Object`, but the unnamed type you create at its initialization ... The difference is in the **type of the variable** not in the **type of the value assigned to it**!

Comment: for sure I understand that behavior caused `Object` variable type v.s. `var` type name. Can you explain why in that case methods comparison for both objects identical, and btw `getSomething` is not among them?

Comment: @BaratSahdzijeu: when you call `getClass()` then you look at the *actual type of the object referenced by the variables*. That is **not** dependent on the type of the variable that holds the reference.

Comment: any way to get `getSomething` method evidence via Reflection API ?
Your comment explained why `true` is returned, but not why `getSomething` is not on the returned list.
I assume the type is not Object, but rather some Object subclass:
e.g.
`Test$1 extends Object`, `Test$2 extends Object`

Comment: @Barat The method is retrievable via reflection. In your question you call [`#getMethods()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods()) which only returns the _public_ methods. If you were to use [`#getDeclaredMethods()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods()) then you'd see the method you're looking for. The documentation goes into more detail.

Answer (score 6):

The section represented as **Non-Denotable Types** in the [JEP 286: Local-Variable Type Inference](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) states:

> Anonymous class types cannot be named, but they're easily
>   understood—they're just classes. Allowing variables to have anonymous
>   class types introduces a useful shorthand for declaring a singleton
>   instance of a local class. We allow them.

Hence the method that you invoke using the `var` is allowed to compile considering the class instance is created and *inferred* as an anonymous class further allowing the method to be invoked.

The [Local Variable Declarators and Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4.1) section of the specification mentions this as a side note along with the example as well:

> ```
> var d = new Object() {};  // d has the type of the anonymous class
> ```
>
> *Note that some variables declared with var cannot be declared with an
>   explicit type, because the type of the variable is not denotable.*

On the other hand, with the first instance what you're trying to perform looks like [Invoking a method of an anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959680/invoking-a-method-of-an-anonymous-class), which fails since the type of `o1` is inferred to be `Object` and that further doesn't have a method called `getSomething`. While if you were to invoke the method `getSomething` and fix the compilation there, you could have used

```
Object o1 = new Object() {
  String getSomething() {
    System.out.println("something happened");
    return "AAA";
  }
}.getSomething();
```

Comment: I'd suggest going to the JLS for the exact specification, JEP is the process to get it included in the JLS and sometimes the phrasing can differ ...

Comment: @JoachimSauer Would surely do that in some time to spare. For now, quoted what I remembered reading through.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I might have just been too late to edit(I can see the JLS quoted in your answer), but I quoted the line which compliments your answer and I hope it is worth keeping as a note for future readers.